# Why is my GUI not showing up? I am trying to make a tic tac toe board but my GUI is not showing up

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am trying to make a tic tac toe game in java but my GUI is just not showing up. It makes a board and you are able to press buttons to play tic tac toe. I am new to java so I have no idea what is wrong. It has no errors and I use repl. What is wrong?

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
private XOButtons[] buttons = new XOButtons[9];
private int turn = 0;
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
XOButtons source = (XOButtons)actionEvent.getSource();
if(turn == 0){
source.toggleX();
setTitle("O Turn");
} else if(turn == 1){
source.toggleO();
setTitle("X's Turn");
}
turn = (turn + 1) % 2;
}
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
   new TicTacToe();
}
  
 public void TicTacToe() {
setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");
setSize(600,600);

setLocation(100,100);
getContentPane().setBackground(Color.CYAN);
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3,5,5));
panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
for(int i=0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
buttons[i] = new XOButtons();
buttons[i].addActionListener(this);
panel.add(buttons[i]);
}
add(panel);
setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Here is my second java file:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
public class XOButtons extends JButton {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private ImageIcon xIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("x.png"));
private ImageIcon oIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("o.png"));
public void toggleX() {
if(getIcon() == null) {
setIcon(xIcon);
} else {
setIcon(null);
}
}
public void toggleO() {
if(getIcon() == null) {
setIcon(oIcon);
} else {
setIcon(null);
}
}
}
```

Also, I have x.png and o.png loaded in.

Comment: That code does not even compile. There is no constructor or even class that matches `new TicTacToe();`

Comment: Am I supposed to replace it with something like JFrame?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code.

Comment: 3) One way to get image(s) for an MRE / SSCCE (as appears in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67302034/418556)) is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). E.G. The code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) hot links to an image embedded in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10861852/418556).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems and less than optimal ways of solving the problem in that code, but this problem was caused by turning the class name (`TicTacToe`) into `Main` and changing the constructor into a method.

This is what results when that is corrected.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;

public class TicTacToe extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    private final XOButtons[] buttons = new XOButtons[9];
    private int turn = 0;

    public TicTacToe() {
        setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");
        setSize(600, 600);

        setLocation(100, 100);
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3, 5, 5));
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new XOButtons();
            buttons[i].addActionListener(this);
            panel.add(buttons[i]);
        }
        add(panel);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        XOButtons source = (XOButtons) actionEvent.getSource();
        if (turn == 0) {
            source.toggleX();
            setTitle("O Turn");
        } else if (turn == 1) {
            source.toggleO();
            setTitle("X's Turn");
        }
        turn = (turn + 1) % 2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TicTacToe();
    }
}

class XOButtons extends JButton {

    private ImageIcon xIcon = null;
    private ImageIcon oIcon = null;

    XOButtons() {
        try {
            xIcon = new ImageIcon(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/in9g1.png"));
            oIcon = new ImageIcon(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCF8S.png"));
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void toggleX() {
        if (getIcon() == null) {
            setIcon(xIcon);
        } else {
            setIcon(null);
        }
    }

    public void toggleO() {
        if (getIcon() == null) {
            setIcon(oIcon);
        } else {
            setIcon(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it might be something wrong with repl as it says that there is an invalid method declaration; return type required where it says                                             
     public TicTacToe() {

Comment: *"it says that there is an invalid method declaration; return type required where it says public TicTacToe()"* In the code in the answer, or in your code? (I can probably guess, but guesses aren't information.)

Comment: In your answer. I copied your code and put it into repl.

Comment: What exactly is 'repl'? I suggest you start an entirely new project, paste the code in my answer, and confirm it works.